# Next_Permutation algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, permutation

I am trying to write an algorithm for getting the next permutation of a given array of integers.
My current code only works for a few inputs.
Thus, I need help figuring out where things went wrong.

The expected output differs from input only for the last three elements. So I checked the implementation of algorithm for last three elements.

```
void Solution::nextPermutation(vector<int> &A) {
    int j, i;
    for (i = A.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        // loop to find i such that A[i-1] < A[i];

        if (A[i - 1] < A[i]) {
            j = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == 0)
        sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    // to give the lowest order if next_permutation is not possible

    if (i > 0) {
        // if next permutation is possible

        // to swap last element and element at j-1 th index

        if (j == A.size() - 1)
            swap(A[j-1], A[A.size() - 1]);
        else {
            for(int k = A.size() - 1; k >= j; k--) {
                if (A[k] > A[j-1]) {
                    swap(A[k], A[j- 1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //to sort the elements after j-1 th index
        sort(A.begin()+j,A.end());
    }
```

Input:

> [444, 994,701, 319, 695, 52]

Expected Output:

> [444,994,701,695,52,319]

Actual Output:

> [444,994,701,52,319,695]

Comment: Parentheses are unbalanced. Are you sure that compiles?

Comment: yeah ,its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Swap is not needed if you are sorting the vector after j - 1.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void nextPermutation(vector<int> &A) {
    int j,i;
    for(i=A.size()-1;i>0;i--){//loop to find i such that A[i-1]<A[i];
        if(A[i-1]<A[i]){j=i;break;}
    }
    if(i==0){sort(A.begin(),A.end());}
     /*to give the lowest order if  next_permutation 
    is not possible*/


    if(i>0){
        //if next permutation is possible
        //to swap last element and element at j-1 th index
        // swap(A[j-1],A[A.size()-1]);
        //to sort the elements after j-1 th index
        std::sort(A.begin()+j,A.end());
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v= {444, 994,701, 319, 695, 52};
    nextPermutation(v);
    for (int i = 0; i< v.size(); i++) {
        std:: cout << v[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

**One more suggestion**: You can completely avoid sort. Find the k in [j+1, ..., n] such that v[k] is the smallest element > v[j], then rotate the vector v[j ... k-1] by one unit clockwise(first element goes to the end).

Comment: Your approach seems to be right but output of your code is not matching with the  output obtained by stl of next permutation.